# Raspberry pi 4 suddenly stopped booting up

Tags: boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os

My raspberry pi suddenly stopped booting up and started giving this message on boot loader.

[image: Bootloader Error Picture]

Please let me kniw, if the sd card has got corrupted or anything else. What should I do?

Comment: `Bad cluster number 0` might indicate a corrupt or defective SD card. A search for the error message led me to e.g. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=294959 or https://maikel.pro/blog/this-might-just-fix-your-corrupt-sd-card-of-your-raspberry-pi/

Comment: "What should I do?" Who knows the picture is illegible. Restore from your backup.

Comment: You may be able to recover data from the card with another machine and place that data on a new sd with a fresh image.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening me when i do too much of overclock, or bad media. Try booting of new SD/USB with fresh new system.